# How to define the main class in an Android App?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, program-entry-point

I'm very newbie in android, I download an example from developer.android.com and I want to create a new class with his layout and modify the main class of the application to start with another layout.

How can I achive this? (the starting class modification).

**[EDIT]**

I achieve this adding to my manifest this:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

But when I do `setContentView(R.layout.mynewlayout);` the loaded layout is the old one...

Any idea why is this happening?

**[EDIT2]**

I'm stupid... the old and the new layout were the same... now is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you start with hello world application ?

Comment: and to add to that ... create a new activity and make this as launcher in manifest and using method startactvity you can call existing activity.

Comment: I already started with the Hello World, but I'm doing some more complex tests :-)

Answer (score 1):

> modify the main class of the application to start with another layout.

To be able to do this, in the onCreate method, you decide on the layout by with the following:

```
setContentView(R.id.layout_id)
```

layout_id is the name of your layout xml file.

> I want to create a new class with his layout

If i understand it correctly, you should copy the layout xml file in his project, in the layout folder, into your own layout folder and using the above method, you can use his layout.

You sould take a look at the [Android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) to get a better grasp of this concept.

Comment: Hi Hakan, problably I don't explain myself very well, I don't want to change the layout for my current main activity, I try to change the main activity (and set it another layout to watch the success :P). Currently I get this modifiying manifest but my current problem is that the new layout is not showing :-S

Answer (score 0):

tell me what the logCat says??

an according to you that android can't show your new layout in main.xml to me so that just i tell you more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Activity, opposed to changing the original and then open up AndroidManifest.xml and **change** the single android:name line from the original Activity to the newly created name.

```
<activity android:name="NewActivity" // Used to be OldActivity
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```